# Query on uploading outbound change set

Tags: change-set

We have multiple individual sandboxes for each developer in our org.

All of them are connected as shown below.

[image]

I have created an outbound changeset from my developer sandbox and I am trying to upload it into one of the other developer's sandbox as shown below.

[image]

And if I press the "Upload" button in the screen as shown below can someone tell me whether there will be an option to point out to a particular sandbox or it will be sent to **all the environments shown in the first image** by default ?.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already created your connections, then yes that is correct, it's when you click on **Upload** it will ask you to which connections you want to upload your outbound change set.